# How do I improve these queries' performance?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a long complicated home page where a **company** is shown, for each **project**, information about recent **events**. The idea is that they have a kind of data-heavy information center from which they can monitor all activity.

I've had trouble getting this page to perform well - two days ago local load times were 4.5s(!) and they are currently at ~2.5s(!). The most alarming part about this horrible performance is that these are the load times with only 3 projects and practically no events. Performance on the live app is slightly better, but not nearly enough.

#### Purpose: Improve load time on home page

Here are the current queries.

```
# controller
@projects = @company.projects.order("project_title ASC").includes({:events => :owner}).search(params[:search], params[:page])

# view
@projects.each do |project|
  @events = project.events.where(:active => true).includes(:owner).order("priority DESC")
end
```

Removing the `.where(:active => true).includes(:owner).order("priority DESC")` is shaving off 1.1 seconds on an app with only 3 projects and 4 events in total.

How should these queries be written optimally? Should indexing play a role in this case?

I've been playing around with database indexes for the looped query in the view but I haven't gotten one to cut down the time yet.

Comment: Could you post the table creation script? Also run the statement through mysql and give us the explain plan as well.

Comment: @dmcnelis - by table creation script, do you mean the original migration that created the company/project/event tables?

Comment: I just encircled the view query with `logger.debug`s and there is nothing in the logs between the two! Here's the load report: `Completed 200 OK in 1480ms (Views: 310.7ms | ActiveRecord: 19.8ms)
`. How come load is 1.5s when Views + AR =~ 330ms...

Comment: My dev environment logs are showing no queries taking longer than 5ms, including all queries run from the view. Performance of each appears to be fine but removing the chunk above is still yielding a huge improvement...

Comment: 1000 5ms queries is 5s. I've found that ActiveRecord has a bad habit of doing a lot of single row queries when one big query with appropriate joins would make more sense. How many queries does each `project.events.where()` turn into and how many trips through the `.each` do you make?

Comment: In my case, there are 3 `.each` loops and fewer than 3 `.where()` queries in each. I just totalled up the time for ALL queries in dev and came to <40ms. In production, the company would have, let's say, between 1 and 30 projects per page, and each project could have up to 30 events each before paginating.

Comment: Not that you are at fault here for doing anything wrong or can you make use of them, but this is why I go around day after day preaching views and stored procedures written by a human.

Comment: @StarShip3000 - You lost me, what do you mean ?

Comment: I think StarShip3000's point is that ORMs tend to put too much stuff between the human and the database and so make it difficult to figure out where performance problems come from and difficult to fix them: too much friendly magic and not enough knowledge about what is really going on.

Comment: @sscirrus mu is too short stated it exactly.

Comment: Can you log the SQL that is being generated? That might shed some light on at least why that is slow. And maybe help those who know Rails let you know how to change your Ruby code to a more optimal query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .includes(:events => :owners) is not doing what you think, as when you call .where on events later you have to retrieve from the data base again.

Also, if your search method is using the events and owners table you may want to used .joins() instead of .includes().

I would make sure you have indexes on every foreign key (xxx_id) and on events active.

I would also give this a shot (not sure if it works, may need some tweaking):

```
class Project < AR::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :active_events,
    :class_name => 'Event',
    :conditions => {:active => true},
    :order => "events.priority DESC"
    :include => :owner
end

#in controller:
@projects = @company.projects.order("project_title ASC").includes(:active_events).search(...)


#in view: (abstract this to a render collection method if possible)
@project.each do |project|
  @events = project.active_events
end
```

Comment: why does `includes(:events => :owners)` not work in this case? Thank you very much for your solution - it has sped up the load time considerably :)

Comment: The includes method tells rails "hey, load all related data in these two tables also!" That works great in most cases, however you include them and THEN later you try to query those relationships with different conditions. At that point rails says "oh, I don't have THIS set of records, guess I better query again". Basically every time you do a .where or a .order you have to hit the db again. I just moved that logic up into your initial include by adding it to a relationship, so when you hit it again rails says "Oh I have that!" That make sense?

Comment: it makes perfect sense. Thank you very much - this is a very helpful answer! +1